# How to view application specific logs while running services using docker-compose

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose

How to view application specific logs while running services using docker-compose, without getting into each of the containers. We have microservices running in Rails, Python, Java in a single docker-compose environment. What would be a cost effective open source solution which we can use for monitoring  + searching logs by the Operations team. We would want to avoid Elasticsearch for this as we don't have a big budget, appreciate your inputs

Answer (score 1):

Elastic search provides free tier as well. [ELK - subscriptions](https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions). You can use `BASIC - FREE AND OPEN`

You can use easily set up logging infrastructure using

ELK - Elastic Search, Logstash, Kibana

filebeat - Log shipper for docker containers - [filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-input-docker.html)

metricbeat - metricbeat for docker - containers

The infrastructure would scale irrespective of how many containers you have.

You can check out some basic monitoring and logging examples here - [link](https://github.com/codeaprendiz/devops-essentials/blob/main/docker-compose-kitchen/README.md)

Answer (score 0):

As well as the Free license mentioned in the other answer, most Elastic tools are available in apache-licensed OSS versions.

Beats agents mostly support autodiscovery in docker and docker-compose, making them really easy to use on an ongoing basis, even with short-lived containers.

It would help if you specify whether the budget constraints are around a) licensing costs, b) time and effort for your Operations team, or c) something else.